# Changing select options using jquery as per rightmove price selection

Tags: jquery, html-select

Hi I've been searching for a bit of code that will work how the rightmove price select boxes work.

Basically you choose the min price and based on this the select box for the max price has its select options changed so that the initial price is the min price selected in the min price select box, the rest of the max price select options are then populated starting from the new min price selection.

They also have a reverse function that if you select a max price first and then select a min price which is greater than the selected max price it will reverse the price options in the 2 selection boxes so the min price then becomes the max price and vice-versa.

I hope this makes sense have a look at the rightmove property search to see what I mean.

Any help much appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="minprice" name="minprice">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">MIN PRICE</option>
        <option value="50000">&pound; 50,000</option>
            <option value="60000">&pound; 60,000</option>
            <option value="70000">&pound; 70,000</option>
            <option value="80000">&pound; 80,000</option>
            <option value="90000">&pound; 90,000</option>
            <option value="100000">&pound; 100,000</option>
            <option value="110000">&pound; 110,000</option>
            <option value="120000">&pound; 120,000</option>
        <option value="200000">&pound; 200,000</option>
            <option value="300000">&pound; 300,000</option>
            <option value="400000">&pound; 400,000</option>
            <option value="500000">&pound; 500,000</option>
            <option value="600000">&pound; 600,000</option>
            <option value="700000">&pound; 700,000</option>
            <option value="800000">&pound; 800,000</option>
            <option value="900000">&pound; 900,000</option>
            <option value="1000000">&pound;1 million+</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">MAX PRICE</option>
        <option value="50000">&pound; 50,000</option>
            <option value="60000">&pound; 60,000</option>
            <option value="70000">&pound; 70,000</option>
            <option value="80000">&pound; 80,000</option>
            <option value="90000">&pound; 90,000</option>
            <option value="100000">&pound; 100,000</option>
            <option value="110000">&pound; 110,000</option>
            <option value="120000">&pound; 120,000</option>
        <option value="200000">&pound; 200,000</option>
            <option value="300000">&pound; 300,000</option>
            <option value="400000">&pound; 400,000</option>
            <option value="500000">&pound; 500,000</option>
            <option value="600000">&pound; 600,000</option>
            <option value="700000">&pound; 700,000</option>
            <option value="800000">&pound; 800,000</option>
            <option value="900000">&pound; 900,000</option>
            <option value="1000000">&pound;1 million+</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried or atleast the HTML/Design

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {         
    var aux;

    if (parseInt($('#min-year').val()) > parseInt($('#max-year').val())) {
       aux = $('#min-year').val();
       $('#min-year').val($('#max-year').val());
       $('#max-year').val(aux);
}
});
```

I hope this help. When the user select the max-year less than min-year the values ​​will be inverted